# Bash: test strings including dollar sign

Tags: bash, string, test

Can someone explain the strange behavior of dollar sign $ in test command?

```
[ "$a" != "$b" ]
echo $?
1
[ "$a" != "b" ]
echo $?
0
```

Why `test "$a" != "$b"`  returns ONE instead of a ZERO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a special character in bash that can be used to expand parameters such as variables or special parameters like your `$?`. If you want to use it in a double-quoted string, you need to escape it with a `\`

```
$ [ "\$a" != "\$b" ]
$ echo "$?"
0
```

Or use single quotes (inside which no character is treated specially) instead of double quotes:

```
$ [ '$a' != '$b' ]
$ echo "$?"
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the test expression uses `$a` and `$b` in double quotes, the shell will interpret these as variables and replace them with their values.

In your code, the variable `a` and `b` are most likely unset.  This means that `$a` and `$b` will be the same value (the empty string).  The `"$a" != "$b"` test will therefore be false (1).

If you want to compare the *strings* `$a` and `$b`, use, for example, single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
if [ '$a' != '$b' ]; then ...; fi
```

This will protect the strings from variable expansion.

Comment: Merci for clarifying things up